# Browsers are not launching from command prompt. Same testng File is working while running through eclipse

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to run my `testng` test cases from command prompt.  I can see browser's instance are created in task manager but it is not launching with given URL. I debugged the code and  found it is failing on `new ChromeDriver()` below line but there is no exception.

On command line, I can see below message :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a) on port 7108
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Browser instance will create in task manager but it will not launch and will not go to next line.

This issue is coming from all browsers on same line.
same code worked well in Eclipse.
Using `Selenium 2.53.0` and `testng 6.9.13` versions

Comment: And what command are you using??

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
        ChromeDriverService service = null;
                try
                {
                    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(chromeDriver))
                            .usingAnyFreePort()
                            .build();
                    service.start();
                }catch(IOException io){}
    if(service.isRunning())
                    {
                        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

                        try{
                            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), cap);
                        }catch (SessionNotCreatedException e) 
                        {
                        }
                    }
```